# "Intrude" faces instead of extruding

Tags: modeling

I want to create a stairs-like extrusion with a face - But kind of inverted, like intruded.

The result should be something like this.
[image: Extrude]

However I don't want to extrude the left face to the top, but instead to intrude the right face to the bottom. But when I do this, the following happens:
[image: Intrude]

I suppose this is exactly the right thing and handled perfectly well by Blender, it's just not what I want. The outer faces still exist, while the top face is just moved to the inside.

I hope you understand what I mean, if not, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like in cegatron's answer, you should use *Loopcut* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>)

Once you have made a new edge loop, delete the faces with <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>*> Faces*, then fill the holes with <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use loop subdivide.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to create a new loop.

That way you can avoid duplicating faces.

[image]
[image]
From the newly created faces extrude the new steps

[image]
 read the manual for this tool here:

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop_subdivide.html?highlight=subdivide

Answer (score 0):

you could try this addon:
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?376618-Add-on-Extrude-and-Reshape
It works to push/pull faces creating needed faces auto filling the holes

Comment: It is generally advised to include more information directly in your answer. If a link no longer works at some point, your answer will still have value.